# node mssql binding in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, binding

I'm new to SQL Server. When I was using MySQL, it was so easy to bind variables using '?'. However, I don't know how to bind variables in `mssql`.

I tried this:

```
const pool = new SQL.ConnectionPool(config, function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to SQL server successfully');
}); 

var Myquery = "INSERT INTO person (idNumber, forename, surname, age, address, maritalStatus)" +
        " VALUES( " + req.body.idNumber + ", " + req.body.forename + ", " + req.body.surname +
        ", " + req.body.age + ", " + req.body.address + ", " + req.body.maritalStatus + " )";

pool.request().query(Myquery, function (err, result) {
           res.json(result);
        })
```

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'single'.

However, when I execute the query I created here (Myquery) directly in SQL Server, it goes smoothly. How can I fix this?

edit:

```
const pool = new SQL.ConnectionPool(config, function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to SQL server successfully');
});

const ps = new SQL.PreparedStatement(pool);
ps.input('param', SQL.NVarChar);
ps.prepare('SELECT * FROM @param', function (err) {
     if (err) console.log('error: ' + err);
    else {
        ps.execute({param: 'person'}, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
    }
});
```

> error: ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.

I used this too:

```
const pool = new SQL.ConnectionPool(config, function (err) {
console.log('Connected to SQL server successfully');
});
pool.request().input('param', SQL.NVarChar, 'person')
.query("SELECT * FROM @param", function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log('error: ' + err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

> error: ConnectionError: Connection is closed.

Comment: What about adding single quotes to your values ? `'" + req.body.maritalStatus + "' )"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need single quotes around your text values:

```
const pool = new SQL.ConnectionPool(config, function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to SQL server successfully');
}); 

    var Myquery = "INSERT INTO person (idNumber, forename, surname, age, address, maritalStatus)" +
        " VALUES( " + req.body.idNumber + ", '" + req.body.forename + "', '" + req.body.surname +
        "', " + req.body.age + ", '" + req.body.address + "', '" + req.body.maritalStatus + "' )";

    pool.request().query(Myquery, function (err, result) {
           res.json(result);
        })
```

Also its a SUPER bad idea to create queries based on inputs this way as it allows SQL injection. You should use @parameters (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/)

Comment: Thank you. It works. But can you show me how I should use binding ? I read the mssql documentation. there was a function 'input'. But I cannot find the correct syntax.

Comment: what node library as you using? mssql? tds?

Comment: I'm using the mssql node module.

Comment: Those are two approaches. I use the prepared statement approach.

Comment: so for your above query: `const pool = new SQL.ConnectionPool(config, function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to SQL server successfully');
});

var Myquery = "INSERT INTO person (idNumber, forename, surname, age, address, maritalStatus)" +
    " VALUES( @idNumber,@forename,@surname,@age, @address, @maritalStatus)";

pool.request().input('idNumber',sql.Int,someId)
              .input('forename',sql.NVarChar,forenameValue)
              ...
              .query(Myquery, function (err, result) {
    res.json(result);
})`

Comment: @KasraGH try putting your code inside the `new SQL.ConnectionPool` callback function.

Also, you cannot parameterize the name of the table you are querying in your `from` clause.

Comment: I did. But get another error. I think it has something to do with the asynchronous behavior of javascript. I have to use async node module

Comment: @KasraGH post your updated code in a new question and I'll try to answer it there.